# Scheme Sum from a to b Iteratively

Tags: scheme, iteration

I am trying to write a procedure that adds all the numbers between a and b. For example if a=1 and b=5, the procedure would add 1+2+3+4+5. Here's what I have so far. I want to write this iteratively. Thanks!

```
(define (sum term a next b)
  (define (iter a result)
    (if (> a b)
        sum
        (iter ?? ??)))
  (iter ?? ??))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, notice that the `sum` procedure receives *four* parameters, clearly you'll *have* to use all of them as part of the solution, in particular, the two procedures will bee needed at some point. Here's what each one represents:

- `term`: function to apply to each element of the sequence
- `a`:    starting number of the range (inclusive)
- `next`: function to determine the next element of the sequence
- `b`:    ending number of the range (inclusive)

For instance, this is how you'd test the procedure with the example in the question:

```
(sum identity 1 add1 5)
=> 15

(= (sum identity 1 add1 5) (+ 1 2 3 4 5))
=> #t
```

But wait, how do we implement it? that's for you to discover - it won't do you any good if we give the answer right away, but I can give you some hints:

```
(define (sum term a next b)
  ; internal procedure for implementing the iteration
  ; a      : current number in the iteration
  ; result : accumulated sum so far
  (define (iter a result) 
    (if (> a b)  ; if we traversed the whole range
        result   ; then return the accumulated value
        (iter    ; else advance the iteration
         ??      ; what's the next value in the range?
         (+      ; accumulate the result by adding
          ??     ; the current term in the range and
          ??)))) ; the accumulated value
  ; time to call the iteration
  (iter ??       ; start iteration. what's the initial value in the range?
        ??))     ; what's the initial value of the sum?
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you have two `iter` calls, and you have to decide which values to put into them:

- For the outer `iter` call, you have to decide what the initial value for `a` and `result` is.

  - For the initial value of `result`, think about what your function should return if `a` were greater than `b` to begin with.
- For the inner `iter` call, you have to decide what the next value for `a` and `result` will be.

  - For the next value of `result`, you should add in the current number to the previous result.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I am relatively new to Scheme. How do I call the function/perform the action? Thanks so much!

Comment: Look at Óscar López's answer; he explains each step very, very well.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of algorithms call for iteration, like simpson's rule for approximating integrals. We can 'fake' the iteration by calling an iterative helper .

```
(define (sum a b)
 (sum-iter a b 0))

(define (sum-iter index n sum)
   (if (= n index)
    (+ sum index) 
    (+  (sum-iter  n (+ index 1) (+ sum index)))
 )
```